# Look for a number in a column and place a 1 or 0 in the result cell

Tags: excel

I'd like to see if a number in one cell exists in a column of numbers, and then have a result in another cell.

My cursor is in cell AW10. (The result cell.)
The number I want to look for is in cell AS10. (Number to find.)
The column to search is D5 - D500. (List of numbers.)
I'd like a 1 for a positive result, or a 0 for a negative result. (In the result cell.)

Is there a formula I can use, or some VB that can be put into a macro.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please start to write your code and then we will help you. we are not going to do it for you.

Comment: Try `=IF(COUNTIF(D5:D500,AS10)>0,1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the absolute lookup range otherwise the lookup range will change when you copy the formula down the rows.

Try this...

In AW10

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$5:$D$500,AS10),1,0)
```

and then copy it down.